# Is it possible to send a custom email template for a specific product in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As in title.

Either, by way of plugin, or by adding a filter to the functions.php file, is it possible to direct the email notifications for specific woocommerce product types?

I.e. Product A will always receive Template A, whereas Product B always receives Template B, and the rest continue to receive their standard New Order customer notifications etc.

Any answers don't need to necessarily be a full in-depth how-to, if you can point me to the correct documentation or other examples that can lead me down the path to getting this working I'll accept it! My google-fu is failing me, only finding dozens of premium WP plugins that do very little for the money.

Comment: Could something like this plugin work? 
https://www.smackcoders.com/documentation/woocommerce-email-customizer/product-based-template
Not tested by me but seems to solve your issue.

Comment: Bought the pro version and it's pretty broken. The support is taking weeks to address simple complaints. I'd say smackcoders is pretty unreliable. At the end of the day I've got some broken code I can work on fixing, but I had to pay $99 for it.